# Migrating from oauth2client to google-auth for retrieving Google ADC access token in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a few python scripts designed to be run by an end user with the GCP permissions then controlled by group-based IAM policies.  To authenticate, the user generates application default credentials (ADC) by running `gcloud auth application-default login` on the CLI.  I then use [oauth2client](https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/)'s GoogleCredentials() and get_access_token() to get the access token:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
access_token = credentials.get_access_token().access_token
```

I then pass `access_token` to an HTTPS request using the `Authorization` header in this format:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

Works fine, but oauth2client was deprecated a few years back and apparently [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io) and [oauthlib](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib/tree/master) should be used instead.  Problem is, I've been completely unable to locate any examples of retrieving the user-generated ADC access token.  Seems like this should work:

```
from google.auth import default

credentials = default()
access_token = credentials.token
```

I'm basing this off the following code that uses Service Accounts and works fine:

```
from os import environ
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

ADC_VAR = 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'] 

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(environ.get(ADC_VAR), scopes=SCOPES)
credentials.refresh(Request())
access_token = credentials.token
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple reasons this wasn't working, but the main thing I missed is [google.auth.default()](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.html) returns a tuple, with the credentials as the first element.  So a working code example is just something like this:

```
from google.auth import default
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

credentials, project_id = default(scopes=SCOPES, quota_project_id='xxxxxx')
credentials.refresh(Request())
access_token = credentials.token
```

Comment: Only use the parameter `quota_project_id` if you are using credentials from the CLI. If you are using a compute service (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, etc), or using a service account do not include it. That parameter is only needed if `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project` has not been completed AND credentials from the CLI are being used.